# Combine Multiple Web Service Results into a Single Knockout ViewModel

Tags: jquery, rest, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I need to call multiple web services to get different bits of information about a resource.  For instance I may have the following calls for a multi-tenant app:

1. GET locations
2. GET locations/{id}/servers
3. GET locations/{id}/tenants
4. etc.

With each of these calls I end up with a different jQuery ajax call to a corresponding web service.  However my UI displays a summary page of sorts that displays a table for the results from each query.  It seems it would be really easy to build a single Knockout ViewModel that then has ObservableArrays for each query result but maybe I'm approaching this incorrectly.  Either way I'm not sure how to consolidate the multiple calls to one model or utilize multiple models for each call.

Does anyone have any documentation or sample code they could share to point me in the right direction?

**Update:** I want to acheive this end result/structure in my Knockout object.  Essentially it is a one to many relationship, one location to many servers or tenants.

```
LOCATION
  - Name
  - ID
  - Date
  - Servers []
  - Tenants []
```

Thanks

Comment: @Steve I've tried both methods but primarily creating two different models.  They bind OK however my displays are mixed amongst each other so assigning a binding context does not work, it fails to render.  It seems to me that a singular model is the best way to go but I have no clue how to bind the child array after the parent binds to the web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is create one view model for the page and update the properties with the values from each call.  I use the ko.mapping plugin with three parameters to update the existing observable array and make the properties observable.  The `ko.mapping.fromJSON` calls will go in the success function of your AJAX call where you get the results, I just made them click handlers for simplicity.
http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/v9XTf/

```
var jsonLocations = '[{"name":"home"},{"name":"work"}]';
var jsonServers = '[{"name":"Mercury"},{"name":"Venus"}]';
var jsonTenants = '[{"name":"Betty"},{"name":"Frank"}]';

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.locations = ko.observableArray();
    self.servers = ko.observableArray();
    self.tenants = ko.observableArray();

    self.loadLocations = function() { ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonLocations, {}, self.locations); };
    self.loadServers  = function() { ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonServers, {}, self.servers); };
    self.loadTenants = function() { ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonTenants, {}, self.tenants); };
}

var my = { vm: new ViewModel() };                                                        

ko.applyBindings(my.vm);​
```

**edit** - [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/6xzFW/1/)

If the locations contain the tenants, you can modify that property on the location, the ko event handler passes the current model to the handler:

```
self.loadServers  = function(location) {
    ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonServers, {}, location.Servers);
};
```

If you're binding with jQuery, you can use `ko.dataFor(element)` to get the model from the context where the element is:

```
$('.loadAll').live('click', function(e) {
    var location = ko.dataFor(this);
    // location can be used in success callback of ajax 
    ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonServers, {}, location.Servers);
    ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonTenants, {}, location.Tenants);
});
```

Comment: This helps a bit.  The problem is the structure.  In essence there is only one Location that then has a couple of standard observable properties like Name, ID, etc. and then contains the arrays for servers and tenants.  I've updated the OP with the structure I'm looking for.  How would I transform your sample to make this work?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and sample.  This points me in the right direction, however I'm starting to question whether or not I want to keep heading down the JS path versus passing staticly-types objects on the server side.  Seems like a lot of work to parse nested objects on the knockout side of things.

Answer (score 0):

If I hear you correctly, you have a viewmodel with an observableArray of locations. each location may have an array of servers and an array of tenants. One way to tackle this is to create an object that stores all the return values. so in that object you may have {locations: [], servers: [], tenants: []} . This are all  off the main root of the object.

When you get your locations, map them to a local model of observables. Add a property called servers to the location object. This will be used for navigation to the servers for that location. the server property could perform a search (slower but more adaptable) or use a memo object to look up the index of the locations. The key is setting up this local in memory object to help track your data and keep the navigation working.

Another option is to simply load the servers for each location into their respective location object on the client. Either way, you create your own model on the client. I rarely ever take exactly what the server gives to me and NOT map to something. BTW - I dont use the mapping plugin for this, but i suppose you could.